# yii2 use wbraganca\dynamicform\DynamicFormWidget;

Tags: php, yii2

При создании все нормально работает то есть добавляет данные в обе таблицы но при обновлении выводить такую ошибку? Не могу понять что означает
The 'model' property must be set and must extend from '\yii\base\Model'.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Этот эксепшн из-за того что в твоей DynamicFormWidget не загружена сама модель. Нужно смотреть в коде, где этот виджет создается. Должно быть что-то в стиле:

```
$widget = DynamicFormWidget::widget(['model' => $myModel]);
```